# Graphic Tablet: how to reduce the sensitivity?

Tags: tablet, xinput

I am running a Huion graphic table in Ubuntu using Digimend. It works fine for most things, but on software that has no pressure control, a line starts to draw as soon as the pen tip is faintly touching the tablet sourface. How can I have a pressure threshold so that the line is drawn only when I apply a certain force on the tablet?
I tried looking into xinput properties, but my device shows a lot of subdevices and each one has a lot of properties...

Specifically, this is the list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION Huion Tablet Pad pad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION Huion Tablet Dial                   id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION Huion Tablet Touch Ring pad         id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION Huion Tablet Pen stylus             id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION Huion Tablet Pen stylus             id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION Huion Tablet Pen eraser             id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HUION Huion Tablet Dial                   id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and these are the properties of the "pad pad" and the "stylus":

```
Device 'HUION Huion Tablet Pad pad':
    Device Enabled (164):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (166): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (297): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (298):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (299):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (300):    10.000000
    Device Node (289):  "/dev/input/event17"
    Wacom Serial IDs (426): 109, -1, 15, -1, 15
    Wacom Serial ID binding (772):  0
    Wacom Pressure Threshold (773): 0
    Wacom Sample and Suppress (774):    2, 4
    Wacom Enable Touch (775):   1
    Wacom Enable Touch Gesture (776):   0
    Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters (777):   0, 0, 250
    Wacom Tool Type (431):  "PAD" (429)
    Wacom Button Actions (778): "Wacom button action 0" (779), "Wacom button action 1" (780), "Wacom button action 2" (781), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "Wacom button action 3" (782), "Wacom button action 4" (783), "Wacom button action 5" (784), "Wacom button action 6" (785), "Wacom button action 7" (786), "Wacom button action 8" (787), "Wacom button action 9" (788), "Wacom button action 10" (789), "Wacom button action 11" (790), "Wacom button action 12" (791)
    Wacom button action 0 (779):    1572865
    Wacom button action 1 (780):    1572866
    Wacom button action 2 (781):    1572867
    Wacom button action 3 (782):    1572872
    Wacom button action 4 (783):    1572873
    Wacom button action 5 (784):    1572874
    Wacom button action 6 (785):    1572875
    Wacom button action 7 (786):    1572876
    Wacom button action 8 (787):    1572877
    Wacom button action 9 (788):    1572878
    Wacom button action 10 (789):   1572879
    Wacom button action 11 (790):   1572880
    Wacom button action 12 (791):   1572881
    Wacom Strip Buttons (792):  "Button StripLeftUp action" (819), "Button StripLeftDown action" (820), "Button StripRightUp action" (821), "Button StripRightDown action" (822)
    Wacom strip action 0 (793): 1572868
    Wacom strip action 1 (794): 1572869
    Wacom strip action 2 (795): 1572868
    Wacom strip action 3 (796): 1572869
    Wacom Wheel Buttons (797):  "Button AbsWheelUp action" (813), "Button AbsWheelDown action" (814), "Button RelWheelUp action" (815), "Button RelWheelDown action" (816), "Button AbsWheel2Up action" (817), "Button AbsWheel2Down action" (818)
    Wacom wheel action 0 (798): 1572869
    Wacom wheel action 1 (799): 1572868
    Wacom wheel action 2 (800): 1572868
    Wacom wheel action 3 (801): 1572869
    Wacom wheel action 4 (802): 1572868
    Wacom wheel action 5 (803): 1572869
    Wacom Panscroll Threshold (804):    13
    Device Product ID (290):    9580, 109
    Wacom Debug Levels (805):   0, 0
    Button AbsWheelUp action (813): 1572954, 524378
    Button AbsWheelDown action (814):   1572955, 524379
    Button RelWheelUp action (815): 1572954, 524378
    Button RelWheelDown action (816):   1572955, 524379
    Button AbsWheel2Up action (817):    1572956, 524380
    Button AbsWheel2Down action (818):  1572957, 524381
    Button StripLeftUp action (819):    1572958, 524382
    Button StripLeftDown action (820):  1572959, 524383
    Button StripRightUp action (821):   1572960, 524384
    Button StripRightDown action (822): 1572961, 524385
```

```
Device 'HUION Huion Tablet Pen stylus':
    Device Enabled (164):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (166): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (297): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (298):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (299):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (300):    10.000000
    Device Node (289):  "/dev/input/event16"
    Wacom Tablet Area (808):    0, 0, 55880, 34925
    Wacom Rotation (809):   0
    Wacom Pressurecurve (810):  0, 0, 100, 100
    Wacom Serial IDs (426): 109, 1, 2, 0, 0
    Wacom Serial ID binding (772):  0
    Wacom Pressure Threshold (773): 27
    Wacom Sample and Suppress (774):    2, 4
    Wacom Enable Touch (775):   1
    Wacom Hover Click (811):    1
    Wacom Enable Touch Gesture (776):   0
    Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters (777):   0, 0, 250
    Wacom Tool Type (431):  "STYLUS" (427)
    Wacom Button Actions (778): "Wacom button action 0" (779), "Wacom button action 1" (780), "Wacom button action 2" (781), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "Wacom button action 3" (782)
    Wacom button action 0 (779):    1572865
    Wacom button action 1 (780):    1572866
    Wacom button action 2 (781):    1572867
    Wacom button action 3 (782):    1572872
    Wacom Pressure Recalibration (812): 1
    Wacom Panscroll Threshold (804):    2600
    Device Product ID (290):    9580, 109
    Wacom Debug Levels (805):   0, 0
```

THanks